# Python - while a long-running loop is going, how to have a thread periodically "do something" in the same scope?

Tags: python, multithreading, lambda

Let's say I have a loop that'll take a while to finish, like reading a long file. How do I make it so every period of time, `x` (milliseconds?), I execute "some code"?

```
while inFile.readable():
    line = inFile.readline()
    print(line)   # I want to do this every few seconds
```

I'd like to do this via threading and lambdas, as an exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
import thread, time

def takes_a_while():

    def print_status():
        while True:
            print i   # print current i every two seconds
            time.sleep(2)

    status_thread = thread.start_new_thread(print_status, ())
    for i in xrange(10000000):
        print '*',
        time.sleep(0.1)
    status_thread.exit()

takes_a_while()
```

Can be done nicer with decorators or contexts, but you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by keeping track of the last time you printed something:

```
last = time.time()
while inFile.readable():
    line = inFile.readLine()
    now = time.time()
    if now - last > 2: # seconds
        print("time up!")
        last = now
```

If your file takes more than two seconds to read, then that loop will print `time up!` every two seconds.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm interested in knowing how to do this with threads, as an exercise, since I don't know how.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this particular task with threads, it just unnecessarily complicates the implementation. (Your original question didn't state that you specifically wanted threads, which is why this answer exists.)

Comment: My original question had "how to have a thread" in the title. I just repeated myself in the body for emphasis.

Comment: Nevertheless, I still don't recommend using a thread for this. Threads are generally more independent tasks, and you definitely don't want to try to run a thread "in the same scope" as another. That's just a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Look into APScheduler it has a very simple cron like interface to run python code in specific intervals.

http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/

I use it to schedule tasks for a project of mine and it is very stable and tested and very easy to extend, if you need other ways to store your jobs.

Hmm, this is a little bit of overkill for what you want now that I went back to your question, but I will leave it as it could be useful for other similar situations for other people.